# HibernateException on session.buildLockRequest with byte[] as primary key

Tags: hibernate, arrays, hibernateexception

I have a user and credit_card entity, user has a collection of credit_card. The primary key for both of these entities i have is a byte[].

*First session:*
 - I opened a new session.
 - Do criteria query on the users table, which actually goes to the DB and fetches user + credit_cards and finally i have a user Object say userObj.
 - Close the session.

*Second session:*
 - I Opened another session.
 - trying to invoke session.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.NONE).lock(userObj);

Now hibernate will try to reattach the detached object, but i get following error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: reassociated object has dirty collection reference
at org.hibernate.event.def.OnLockVisitor.processCollection(OnLockVisitor.java:71)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:122)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:83)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:77)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.process(AbstractVisitor.java:144)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractReassociateEventListener.reassociate(AbstractReassociateEve    ntListener.java:101)
at   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLockEventListener.onLock(DefaultLockEventListener.java:82)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLock(SessionImpl.java:774)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLock(SessionImpl.java:766)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.access$600(SessionImpl.java:156)
```

I tried to debug it in the hibernate code, and found out, that hibernate tries to check if the passed object's collection (credit_cards) is actually owned by user (which is user1).

So somewhere deep down the code in hibernate, it seems like it is checking for the equality with **equals method** of the primary keys of the passed object (which is user1) and another object what it is calling a snapshot object.
Since byte[] is essentially an array and fails on equals check and throw the above error.
I know i can do above work in just one session, but this is just a scenario.

I tried using Long/Integer as a primary key and it works just fine, since it passes the equality check.

Hibernate version : 3.6.9.Final (i tried to take a look at the 4.1.1.Final version as well, but files/code which throws this error are not changed)
DB : SQL server

Is it a issue in hibernate or i am doing anything wrong ?

Comment: My colleague has reported this as a bug on hibernate: [https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7180](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7180)

Answer (score 1):

use a String instead of a byte[] as primary key. it can carry same value and will pass the **equals**  method

```
String myId = new String(bytes);

myId.getBytes();
```

it is not an hibernate issue.

Comment: Yes, i tried that and it is working fine if i use Long, but is there any solution of this problem with using byte[] as primary key?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue in Hibernate. The class of the ID must implement hashCode and equals properly. `byte[]` doesn't, so it's not a valid ID class. Using a byte[] as an ID is, IMO, a really bad idea. A Long is a really better idea. If you really want to keep your byte array, then wrap it into a custom type, or transform it into a String using Base64 or Hex encoding.

Comment: I agree and i know using byte[] may not be the best practice. But my question is why byte[] is not supported for this kind of situations, or is there any list of non-supported/non-recommended types from hibernate ?

Comment: The ID class must implement equals and hashCode properly. That is the rule. Two different instances representing the same value in database must be equal, and have the same hashCode.